# Magento2: broken layout after installing extension and css is missing

Tags: magento2, frontend

I've just **installed a plugin** and now **magento isn't working** anymore.

Firstly i thought this was due to the **plugin** but even after **disabling/removing the plugin the problem persists**.

Comment: can anyone help me out fix this issue , i have installed weltpixel extension and after that css are missing layout has been changed .and soon i have disabled and removed the extension but also that problem persist , please guys help me .

Answer (score 1):

Run following commands and all will be fine

```
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: thank for your reply @shoaib munir, i've fixed this issue

Comment: what was the issue? did you fix using above commands?

Comment: CSS files were missing, I've deleted the pub/static folder and uploaded backup files

Comment: That's good. :)